# What does the following notation mean in the enclosed commutative diagram for exact sequence?

Tags: notation, exact-sequence

The following is taken from: $\textit{Partial Differential Control Theory Vol 1: Mathematical tools}$ by J F. Pommaret

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Proposition 1.59.}$ Let

$$0\to M'\xrightarrow{f}M\xrightarrow{g}M''\to 0$$

be a short exact sequence of $A-$modules.

$(i)$ If $M'$ and $M''$ are finitely generated, then $M$ is also finitely generated.

$(ii)$ If $M$ is finitely presented and $M'$ is finitely generated, then $M''$ is also finitely presented.

> $\textit{Proof.}$  We have the following commutative and exact diagram:
>
> [image]
>
> The left vertical column is a finite presentation of $M$ where $F$ is a free module and $K$ is finitely generated.  The kernel $L$ of the composition $F\to M\to M''$ is containing $K$ as a submodule and by chasing we obtain an isomorphism $M'\equiv L/K.$  Accordingly, $L/K$ is finitely generated and $L$ is finitely generated too because of $i$).  It follows that $M''$ is finitely presented.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In the proof above for part $(ii)$ of Proposition 1.59,

the notation:

[image]

I would like to know what it means in the context of the commutative diagram.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for $F \xrightarrow{id_F} F$.

Comment: is that an equivalent notation for the identity map arrow when drawing commutative diagram for exact sequences?

Comment: @Seth Yes, this is frequently used.

Comment: ah okay, thank you for clearing that up for me.